# How to connect a scrollbar to a panel in VC++?

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

I need to create a panel to display a long radiobutton form with a scrollbar in VC++ (like the following picture). Since I have hundreds of radio buttons, I cannot show all at once. I need to use a scrollbar to control the current position of the radiobutton form. How I can make the scrollbar connect to the panel to do this task?

[image: the image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing code to synchronize a separate scroll bar control with a `Panel` control is possible, but it's definitely the hard way of doing things.

Instead, consider setting the [`AutoScroll` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll.aspx) of your `Panel` control to `true`. When this property is enabled and the control has a virtual size larger than its visible boundaries, a scroll bar will automatically appear. Much easier.

You can set this property either in the designer, or through code in your form's constructor:

```
myPanel.AutoScroll = true;
```